# How to write an AST selector for class decorator and ident rule using @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to exclude some nodes from the `@typescript-eslint/ident` rule (since Eslint does not work properly with class decorators).

My Typescript looks like the following:

```js
@MyDecorator({
    name: 'MyName',
    options: [{
        name: 'foo',
        type: 'Boolean',
        required: false,
        default: 'True',
    }]
})
```

Eslint complains about too many indentation characters so I want to ignore the MyDecorator from the rule, like so:

```js
    ...,
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", "tab", {
        "SwitchCase": 1,
        "ignoredNodes": [
            "[expression.callee.name=MyDecorator] *"
        ]
    }]
    ...
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different selectors (using `astexplorer.net` for reference). But I think I'm missing out some fundamental detail on how eslint works with selectors.
For example, I would expect `Decorator *` to target everything inside all decorators but it does not. Why? What am I missing?

The only selectors I got working are `Program *` and `[type=Program] *` but of course those target everything so I can't use that.

I'm using eslint v8.56.0.